# Coded UI Test Builder - “Last mouse action was not recorded” and it fails to record the action

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm using codedUI test Builder, initially it was worked fine and after the windows update i faced an issue like, it was hanged while doing a record, literally its not taking any mouse action always showed message **Last mouse action was not recorded**.

I looked on the below link, 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41788/coded-ui-builder-vs2017-will-not-record-any-mouse.html

Its not worked out for me because, they are saying as windows update cause an issue but i had a latest windows updates

Below are the details to bring a better solution

*My last windows Update* : 2019-02 Servicing Stack Update for Windows 10 Version 1703 for x64-based Systems (KB4487327)

*Visual Studio Version* : VS enterprise 2015

*Coded UITest Builder* : "14.0.23107.0"

Please let me know if need more info and do help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just checked, I'm not having this problem on a win10 pro with vs2017, both latest.
It's not because it has been fixed in the past, that it can be broken again now. So I suggest you to file a bug with Microsoft and let them figure it out for you. If you are unsure about whether it's caused by the update or not, you could always try to rollback the update. If that solved your problem, you're 100% sure it was the update causing it. You can view/uninstall updates by navigating to "View installed updates" in the "programs and features" window.

Comment: thanks for suggested me, i will try to do that.